# Calculating the complexity of the function

Tags: recursion, big-o, time-complexity

I have writing a function for calculating the length of longest increasing sequence. Here **arr[]** is array of length n. And **lisarr** is of length of n to store the length of element i.

I am having difficulty to calculate recurrence expression which is a input for master theorem.

```
int findLIS(int n){
        if(n==0)
            return 1 ;
        int res;
        for(int i=0;i<n;i++){
            res=findLIS(i);
            if(arr[n]>arr[i] && res+1>lisarr[n])
                lisarr[n]=res+1;
        }
        return lisarr[n];
    }
```

Please give the way to calculate the recurrence relation.
Should it be 
`T(n)=O(n)+T(1)`?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It is `O(2^n)`. Let's calculate exact number of iterations and denote it with `f(n)`. Recurrence relation is `f(n) = 1 + f(n-1) + f(n-2) + .. + f(1) + f(0)`, with `f(1)=2` and `f(0)=1`, which gives `f(n)=2*f(n-1)`, and finally `f(n)=2^n`.

**Proof by induction:**

Base n=0 -> Only one iteration of the function.
Let us assume that `f(n)=2^n`. Then for input `n+1` we have `f(n+1) = 1 + f(n) + f(n-1) + .. + f(1) + f(0) = 1 + (2^n + 2^(n-1) + .. + 2 + 1) = 1 + (2^(n+1) - 1)=2^(n+1).`. Number one at the beginning comes from the part outside of the `for` loop, and the sum is the consequence of the `for` loop - you always have one recursive call for each `i` in `{0,1,2,..,n}`.

Comment: how T(n) = n-1 + T(n-1) + T(n-2) + .. + T(1) + T(0) =>> 2^n ??

Comment: @YS - Had a mistake, please see the edited answer. I can provide you a proof by induction if you like.

Comment: Yes please .. add that one also

Comment: @YS. Edited, let me know if anything is left unclear.